# I need a way to show only the vertical lines in a table using bootstrap.

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am using BootStrap and need a way to show only the vertical lines in a table .

I've tried to add border-left and border-right, both with :1px solid #red;, to both the table and the seperate td's. but it won't add the border color.

So what im looking for is an easy way to create these vertical lines

Comment: 1px solid red; ... no # symbol.  Only use the # symbol if you want to specify rgb values as #rrggbb

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here are the CSS rules to do this.

```css
table.table tbody tr td,
table.table thead tr th,
table.table thead {
  border-left: 1px solid red;
  border-right: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <h2>Bordered Table</h2>

  <p>The .table-bordered class adds borders to a table:</p>
  <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
        <th>Email</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Mary</td>
        <td>Moe</td>
        <td>mary@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>July</td>
        <td>Dooley</td>
        <td>july@example.com</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Vanburenx, I want table border and table heading bottom row, can you please help me to do that. Thank you.

Comment: You should post an image or something because it isn't clear what you're trying to do: your question says "vertical lines". Are you trying to put a border around the whole table and the vertical separations but not the rows?

Comment: My recquirement is like that: Around the whole table, border should be there, vertical line should be there and one row should be there down to thead.(no other rows means according to you,down to First name,last name,email one row should be there).

Comment: Your CSS code is a bit dirty right now, I've prefixed it and this is the result(it still works) :
`tbody td,
tr th,
thead {
  border-right: 2px solid red;
}
`

Answer (score 0):

The below CSS you can add separately.

```
table.table thead tr th{
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nanduh/p63q4pm4/

or you need red border for table??